# Translation invariance for scalar field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, symmetry

How can I see that for a scalar field

$$\phi(x)=e^{i\hat{p}\cdot x}\phi(0)e^{-i\hat{p}\cdot x}$$

if we have translation invariance?

Comment: If $U(\Lambda,a)$ is a Poincaré transformation acting on the Hilbert space a scalar field obeys, *by definition*, $$U(\Lambda,a)\phi(x)U(\Lambda,a)^{-1} = \phi(\Lambda x+a).$$ Your equation is a particular case with $\Lambda=1$ and $a=x$, and where we apply the transformation to the operator $\phi(0)$.

Comment: related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/532254/226902 ,  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/566963/226902 ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a straightforward application of [Lagrange's shift operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_operator), namely the formal rewriting of Taylor's expansion around 0. ($\phi$ being translationally invariant means its form does not change under translations--only its argument.)
However, you must be very careful with the labelling of your double-duty variables, since the momentum operator acts to shift the implicit "*x*" variable of the field, starting from 0, by an amount *x*. To avoid confusion, and mistakes, we rename that shift to *y*. Work in one dimension, as extension to more dimensions is self-evident.

Now, when you are working in the x-representation, the arguments of the field, you have $\hat p=-i\hbar \partial_x$, hence Lagrange's/Taylor's shift is just
$$
e^{y  \cdot   \partial_x }\phi(x)= \phi(x+y) e^{y  \cdot   \partial_x } ~~~\leadsto \\
e^{y \cdot   \partial_x  }\phi(x) e^{-y \cdot   \partial_x } = \phi(x+  y)
$$
for an arbitrary differentiable function $\phi(x)$.

Now, take *x=0*,
$$
e^{iy \cdot   \hat p/\hbar }\phi(0) e^{-iy \cdot   \hat p /\hbar  } = \phi(  y),$$
and rename $ y\to x$, to get your dimensionally consistent expression. (Instead, you appear to have set $\hbar=1$.)